# Why is the fpcgisock= socket found in apache logs folder?

Tags: apache-2.2, log-files

The listing of apache logs folder in my hosting server is as follows:

```
someuser@machine [~]# ls -al /usr/local/apache/logs
total 86980
drwxr-xr-x  2 root   root       4096 Apr 30 09:18 ./
drwxr-xr-x 17 root   root       4096 Jan  1 13:54 ../
-rw-r--r--  1 root   root   87938452 May  6 10:46 access_log
-rw-r--r--  1 root   root    1094200 May  6 10:24 error_log
srwx------  1 nobody root          0 Jan  1 12:11 fpcgisock=
-rw-r--r--  1 root   root          6 Apr 30 09:18 httpd.pid
-rw-r-----  1 root   root          0 Jan  1 11:44 modsec_audit.log
-rw-r-----  1 root   root          0 Jan  1 11:44 modsec_debug_log
-rw-r--r--  1 nobody root          0 Apr 30 09:18 ssl_scache.dir
-rw-r--r--  1 nobody root          0 Apr 30 09:18 ssl_scache.pag
-rw-r--r--  1 root   nobody      241 Mar 18 16:03 suexec_log
-rw-r--r--  1 root   root          4 Mar 19 00:13 suexec_log.offset
```

I can see that `fpcgisock=` file is a socket. It puzzled me to find a `socket` file in the apache logs folder. Is that file normal? If so what is it for.

Comment: Presumably because it's configured to keep its socket there. Check your httpd.conf file and any virtual host files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`fpcgisock=` is a frontpage socket file, that is used by frontpage extenstion. If you are facing any issue in apache you should check logs.
When we compile apache with frontpage extenstion, it automatically creates the `fpcgisock=' in apache logs directory.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. :) Why is that file put in apache logs folder?

Comment: When we compile apache with frontpage extenstion, It atuomatically create it in apache logs directory.

Comment: Could you add that information also to your answer so that I can mark it as accepted answer. :)

Comment: Also it would be of great help if you could add a possible reference to this information. I checked for it, but couldn't find any.

Comment: Saji: In my training days I had also searched for the same but no results. I had asked it same from my senior and according to them its a sock file of frontpage.

Comment: That's interesting. Thanks for the help. I myself have edited and added the other part to the answer.